# I get syntax error when i call script from c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a program that will allow easier management of Arduino projects. So I wrote bash script that creates all the necessary folders and files for me and when I execute it I runs like champ. Because I want to change directory in the working terminal inside the script I run script like this

```
. ./initialize.sh
```

This is also working great, but because I am writing C++ program, sourcing this script from program is giving me headache.

So inside a program I run this script like this:

```
system(". /usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh");
```

and then when I run the program I get this error:

> sh: 25: /usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")

Running the script from the program like this:

```
system("/usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh");
```

works without error but it runs in subshell.

Syntax error points to this line in script

```
options=("uno" "mega" "mega2560" "atmega8" "atmega168" "atmega328" "pro" "pro5v" "pro328" "pro5v328")
```

How come that when I run this script outside of the program it's working like champ, but run this script from program and you have a problem ?

EDIT:
Script code

```
   #!/bin/bash

BLACK='\033[0;30m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
BROWN='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LGRAY='\033[0;37m'
DGRAY='\033[1;30m'
LRED='\033[1;31m'
LGREEN='\033[1;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
LBLUE='\033[1;34m'
LPURPLE='\033[1;35m'
LCYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'
NC='\033[0m'

makefile()
{
  BOARD="default"
  PS3='Chose your board: '
  options=("uno" "mega" "mega2560" "atmega8" "atmega168" "atmega328" "pro" "pro5v" "pro328" "pro5v328")
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do case $opt in 
    "uno") BOARD="uno"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/uno/board-info.h .
    MCU="atmega328P"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "mega") BOARD="mega" 
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/mega/board-info.h .
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "mega2560") BOARD="mega2560"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/mega2560/board-info.h .
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "atmega8") BOARD="atmega8"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/atmega8/board_-nfo.h .
    MCU="atmega8"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "atmega168") BOARD="atmega168"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/atmega168/board-info.h .
    MCU="atmega168"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "atmega328") BOARD="atmega328"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/atmega328/board-info.h .
    MCU="atmega328P"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "pro") BOARD="pro"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/pro/board-info.h .
    MCU="unknow"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "pro5v") BOARD="pro5v"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/pro5v/board-info.h .
    MCU="unknown"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;

  "pro328") BOARD="pro328"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/pro328/board-info.h .
    MCU="atmega328P"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  "pro5v328") BOARD= "pro5v328"
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/boards_info/pro5v328/board-info.h .
    MCU="atmega328P"
    F_CPU="16000000UL"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Error : Input is not valid"
    echo "Exiting..."
    return 1 
    ;;
    esac
    break
  done
  [ -e Makefile ] && rm Makefile
  read -p "Do you want to configure your Makefile settings [Y/n]: " CONFIGURE
  if { [ "$CONFIGURE" == "Y" ] || [ "$CONFIGURE" == "y" ]; }; then
    read -p "Enter your MCU: " MCU
    read -p "Enter F_CPU: " F_CPU
  fi
  read -p "Enter ARDUINO_PORT: " ARDUINO_PORT
  echo "ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino">>Makefile
  echo "BOARD_TAG = $BOARD">>Makefile
  echo "ARDUINO_PORT = $ARDUINO_PORT">>Makefile
  echo "NO_CORE = 1">>Makefile
  echo "AVRDUDE_ARD_PROGRAMMER = arduino">>Makefile
  echo "HEX_MAXIMUM_SIZE = 30720">>Makefile
  echo "AVRDUDE_ARD_BAUDRATE = 115200">>Makefile
  echo "#ISP_LOW_FUSE = 0xFF">>Makefile
  echo "#ISP_HIGH_FUSE = 0xDA">>Makefile
  echo "#ISP_EXT_FUSE = 0x05">>Makefile
  echo "#ISP_LOCK_FUSE_PRE = 0x3F">>Makefile
  echo "#ISP_LOCK_FUSE_POST = 0x0F">>Makefile
  echo "MCU = $MCU">>Makefile
  echo "F_CPU = $F_CPU">>Makefile
  echo "VARIANT = standard">>Makefile
  echo "ARDUINO_LIBS =">>Makefile
  echo "include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk">>Makefile
  echo "$BOARD|$MCU|" >> .avrduino.txt

  clear
  echo -e "${LGREEN}Makefile settings${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}ARDUINO_DIR = ${LRED}/usr/share/arduino ${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}BOARD_TAG = ${LRED}$BOARD${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}ARDUINO_PORT = ${LRED}$ARDUINO_PORT${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}NO_CORE = ${LRED}1${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}AVRDUDE_ARD_PROGRAMMER = ${LRED}arduino${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}HEX_MAXIMUM_SIZE = ${LRED}30720${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}AVRDUDE_ARD_BAUDRATE = ${LRED}115200${NC}"
  echo -e "${DGRAY}#ISP_LOW_FUSE = ${RED}0xFF${NC}"
  echo -e "${DGRAY}#ISP_HIGH_FUSE = ${RED}0xDA${NC}"
  echo -e "${DGRAY}#ISP_EXT_FUSE = ${RED}0x05${NC}"
  echo -e "${DGRAY}#ISP_LOCK_FUSE_PRE = ${RED}0x3F${NC}"
  echo -e "${DGRAY}#ISP_LOCK_FUSE_POST = ${RED}0x0F${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}MCU = ${LRED}$MCU${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}F_CPU = ${LRED}$F_CPU${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}VARIANT = ${LRED}standard${NC}"
  echo -e "${LBLUE}ARDUINO_LIBS =${NC}"

}

initializeProject()
{
  read -p "Project name: " PROJECT_NAME
  if [ ! -e PROJECT_NAME ]; then
    mkdir $PROJECT_NAME
    cd $PROJECT_NAME
    makefile #Call function that makes makefile
    cp -r /usr/lib/avrduino/data/include/ .
    echo -e "${LGREEN}Project created successfully ${NC}"
  else 
    echo "AVRduino: Project with name [ $PROJECT_NAME ] already exists. "
    echo "AVRduino: Stop project wizard and exit."
  fi
}

clear
initializeProject
```

Comment: Is it a typo in you post or do you actually have `. /usr` in your code?

Comment: Does the first line of the script have the #! bits?

Comment: . /usr is not typo,  http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip

Comment: It might be that `system()` calls a different shell actually as you have in your terminal. Often seen this kind of error.

Comment: Thats why i call this script with . /usr

Comment: @ACVoltage How should that help actually?

Comment: And the C++ code? In a [mcve]

Comment: @FirstStep In question i wrote C++ code  that i used, in minimal form. This line is only line in function that I have and that function is called when you run program with no arguments. I don't think that anything else from C++ program is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` doesn't execute the script as a process, it only loads it into your current shell process.

In that context, your "shebang" line, `#!/bin/bash`, is just a comment.
(You can put `#! doodle poodle noodle` there and it will run just as well.)

When you use `system`, it executes in `/bin/sh`, and thus your `bash` script has syntax errors.

One way to execute scripts is to make them executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh
```

and then you can just pass it directly to `system`:

```
system("/usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh");
```

Or, you could explictly execute it in `bash`:

```
system("/bin/bash /usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh");
```

---

OK, here's a way one might solve your "changing directory" problem:

Rewrite `initialize.sh` so it takes the project name as an argument instead of asking for it interactively (that's how normal Unix tools work, so stick with it).

Then add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
make_project()
{
    /usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh "$1" && cd "$1"
}
```

Then you can say `make_project foo` and get transported to the directory "foo".

Comment: Any idea how to use CD command so that when script uses this command working directory in current terminal is changed ?

Comment: @ACVoltage You can't - see my comment on the other answer. You need to rethink your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is the misplaced shebang causing a default shell to be run - make sure the shebang is at the beginning of the first line

```
#!/bin/bash
# rest of script
```

If that does not work change your system call to

```
system("/bin/bash /usr/lib/avrduino/script/initialize.sh");
```

Comment: So i changed system call, and it works but not the way i want it. Just to see that maybe i didn't understand this. If i have cd $PROJECT_NAME should this change working directory in my terminal from which i called my program. Because I am aiming for that.

Comment: Please accept the solution then - now you have a new problem

Comment: @ACVoltage `system` creates a new process, with its own working directory, and your C++ program also has its own. Changing any of them will not affect the shell you execute your program from.